# Parsing a csv file in perl

Tags: perl, csv

I am using the following code for reading the last line of a csv file. How do I split the line received into an array?

```
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'server1-20130205.csv', mode=>O_RDONLY or die $!;
print $file[-1];
```

Comment: You need to show us that line. We don't know what the fields look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV).

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv    = Text::CSV->new;
my $status = $csv->parse($file[-1]);
my @fields = $csv->fields;
```

Using `$file[-1]` assumes there are no newlines in your fields.

Answer (score 2):

What's about CPAN module: Text::CSV

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). Assuming your field seperator is a comma, do it like this:

```
my $data = split /,/, $file[-1];
```